# Swagger UI - deepLinking

Tags: http-status-code-404, swagger, deep-linking, swagger-ui, springfox

I am using springfox-swagger2 and springfox-swagger-ui. both version 2.9.2
I have enabled deepLinking with this code:

```
 @Bean
public UiConfiguration swaggerUiConfig() {
    return UiConfigurationBuilder.builder().deepLinking(true).build();
}
```

Somehow it suddenly stopped working, it doesnt redirect me to method in link...
It works only on controllers, for example this works
http://localhost:8080/api/swagger-ui.html#/email-controller/
but not this http://localhost:8080/api/swagger-ui.html#/email-controller/getFullEmailListUsingGET

Any ideas?

I tried older version 2.7.0 and there it works...

Edit: I solved this by using version 2.8.0 where deepLinking works correctly for both controllers and operations. Design of 2.8.0 looks like 2.9.2, 2.7.0 was also working but the design was older.